# Comparing double integral and single integral (finding which one is larger)

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Hi I have two equations 
$$F(a):=\int^{\bar{x}}_{a}\int^{x}_{\underline{x}}2(x-c)\, dy \, dx$$
$$G(b):=\int^{\bar{x}}_{b}(y-c)\,dy$$
where $a,b,c \in [\underline{x}, \bar{x}]$ and $a>b>c$

I have tried to subtract, but it gives me really messy equation and as I can't tell if one is larger than the other. but when I use numerical solution It gives me that $F(a)>G(b)$.

Is there any other way to compare to equations than subtracting?